# How do the electrons in a current-carrying wire move?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, electrons, electric-current, conductors

How do the electrons in a current-carrying wire move? Do they move in straight line, zig-zag or randomly while attracted to the positive charge? Picture or video examples are welcomed.

Comment: @Ghoster sorry about that, I will edit that part

Comment: Here are two relevant Wikipedia articles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_energy

Comment: sorry @Ghoster but I can't understand mathematical explanations, so do they move randomly while still propagate in the direction to the positive charge?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html

Comment: *they move randomly while still propagate in the direction to the positive charge* Yes. The random motion is fast but not relativistic. The overall drift motion is very slow.

Comment: The thing you are asking for is inherent quantum mechanical. Any attempt to think of them classically can at best give you a broken picture. Quite many brightest minds spent decades trying to figure out how balls colliding with a lattice would behave, and all of that turn out to be useless in understanding how electrons actually move in a wire.

Comment: @NaturallyInconsistent yes, QM is involved, the velocity is uncertain, but small enough that in the mascrocopic point of view, the motion should be collective at low temperature.

Comment: @M06-2x there is no hope for a self-consistent classical understanding of the phenomena. If you accept arbitrary _ad hoc_ arguments, of course you can get a lot of weird partial answers. I never denied that. And it is not about uncertainty principle. It is about the fact that the electrons are delocalised waves in the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that electrons follows the laws of quantum mechanics. Yes, they're particles, but also has a wave behavior.

This is a video that explain it better.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGJqykotjog